# snort make file gives error

Tags: c++, compilation, pcre, snort

I have got this error messge when creating snort make file?

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.a(pcre_compile.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against >`.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/lib/libpcre.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How i can get out of this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying `libpcre.a` in your make file for linking, specify `libpcre.so`.

This should get you out of the error!

Thanks!