# Homebrew / TinyTDS / FreeTDS bundle error

Tags: activerecord, homebrew, freetds, tiny-tds

I used homebrew (linux port) to install freeTDS and am trying to deploy /bundle install my app with gem tinytds. I get this error output when doing bundle install

```
Installing tiny_tds (0.5.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

/usr/bin/ld: /opt/homebrew/lib/libsybdb.a(dblib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/opt/homebrew/lib/libsybdb.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

Pretty similar to this fix, but I don't have the files referred to in my folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119224/1130736

Contents of homebrew lib folder:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib$ ls
libct.a  libsybdb.a
```

Full error dump:

```
full error dump:

Installing tiny_tds (0.5.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for sybfront.h... yes
checking for sybdb.h... yes
checking for tdsdbopen() in -lsybdb... yes
checking for ct_bind() in -lct... yes
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/gcc -I. -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_ICONV_OPEN -DHAVE_SYBFRONT_H -DHAVE_SYBDB_H -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I'/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include'    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o client.o -c client.c
client.c: In function ‘tinytds_err_handler’:
client.c:52: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
client.c: In function ‘tinytds_msg_handler’:
client.c:100: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/bin/gcc -I. -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_ICONV_OPEN -DHAVE_SYBFRONT_H -DHAVE_SYBDB_H -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I'/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include'    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o result.o -c result.c
/usr/bin/gcc -I. -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_ICONV_OPEN -DHAVE_SYBFRONT_H -DHAVE_SYBDB_H -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I'/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/include'    -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o tiny_tds_ext.o -c tiny_tds_ext.c
/usr/bin/gcc -shared -o tiny_tds.so client.o result.o tiny_tds_ext.o -L. -L/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib -Wl,-R/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib -L/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib -Wl,-R/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib -L/opt/homebrew/lib -Wl,-R/opt/homebrew/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L. -L'/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib'  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lct -lsybdb  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc 
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/homebrew/lib/libsybdb.a(dblib.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/opt/homebrew/lib/libsybdb.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [tiny_tds.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/ext/tiny_tds/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing tiny_tds (0.5.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install tiny_tds -v '0.5.1'` succeeds before bundling.'
```

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I run fedora, but the fix for me is

```
sudo yum install freetds-devel
```

I am pretty sure that you just need to have the development package of freetds for this to work.  After I had the devel package, my

```
gem install tiny_tds
```

worked perfectly.

Comment: for ubuntu sudo apt-get install freetds-dev

Answer (score 10):

Install FreeTDS with homebrew: `brew install freetds`.

Then, this installation should work: `gem install tiny_tds`

Comment: this isn't working for me because it doesn't make the `lsybdb.so` file

Answer (score 0):

### Installing tiny_tds on the Mac:

**Installing the tiny_tds gem with bundler requires that FreeTDS be installed first, and also that bundler be told where FreeTDS is located.**

First, install FreeTDS:

```
brew install freetds
```

By default, tiny_tds will look in certain locations, but freetds, as installed by homebrew, will not be found in any of them:

```
looking for freetds headers in the following directories:
 - /opt/local/include
 - /opt/local/include/freetds
 - /usr/local/include
 - /usr/local/include/freetds
looking for freetds library in the following directories:
 - /opt/local/lib
 - /opt/local/lib/freetds
 - /usr/local/lib
 - /usr/local/lib/freetds
```

So, first you need to find exactly where the freetds lib and include directories are:

```
ls -l /opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds
```

At the time this is posted, the version of freetds installed by brew is 1.3.3, so that is the directory shown by that `ls -l`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  15 [username]  admin  480 Dec  7 15:36 1.3.3
```

Then, cd into that folder to see its contents:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.3.3
ls -l
```

You will find the include and lib directories for freetds in that folder.

Then, tell bundler to tell tiny_tds where to find them:

```
bundle config set --global build.tiny_tds --with-freetds-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.3.3
```

Now, you can `bundle` and the tiny_tds gem will be built.

Answer (score -1):

I got same problem, I solved it with these two commands:
brew install freetds

And you need to install gem with x64 flag:
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  gem install tiny_tds