# Unable to install tiny_tds on Mac OS X Yosemite v10.10.2

Tags: macos, operating-system, tiny-tds

I am using RubyMine IDE on MAC OS X yosemite. On trying to install tiny_tds its giving the following error

sudo gem install tiny_tds -v '0.6.2'

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no

checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes

checking for sybfront.h... yes

checking for sybdb.h... yes

### checking for tdsdbopen() in -lsybdb... no

### freetds is missing.

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

--with-opt-dir

--without-opt-dir

--with-opt-include

--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include

--with-opt-lib

--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib

--with-make-prog

--without-make-prog

--srcdir=.

--curdir

--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

--enable-lookup

--disable-lookup

--with-iconv-dir

--without-iconv-dir

--with-iconv-include

--without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include

--with-iconv-lib

--without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/

--with-freetds-dir

--without-freetds-dir

--with-freetds-include

--without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include

--with-freetds-lib

--without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/

--with-iconvlib

--without-iconvlib

--with-sybdblib

--without-sybdblib

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.2/ext/tiny_tds/gem_make.out

I have installed freetds

brew install freetds

and I can see it when I do brew list

but again when I do sudo gem install tiny_tds , it gives me error as freetds missing.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did `gem install tiny_tds` not work?

FYI - Using `sudo` with `gem install` is not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted at [Homebrew / TinyTDS / FreeTDS bundle error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997722/homebrew-tinytds-freetds-bundle-error/70270949#70270949), in addition to `brew install freetds`, you may also need to tell the gem where to find freetds.

If you are using bundler, you can do that by configuring bundler.

For example (depending where exactly homebrew installed freetds):

```
bundle config set --global build.tiny_tds --with-freetds-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.3.3
```