# Snort Error: plugbase.c: Undefined reference to: "Setup"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, undefined-reference, snort

I am at a loss what to do and i hope somebody could solve this problem or give me a useful hint.

I am trying to add a preprocessor and a corresponding detection-plugin into Snort.
(Including the preprocessor was without any error but is useless without the corresponding detection-plugin)

I already included the necessary parts of code into the source files and copied all necessary files in the right place.

"Configure" is running without any errors:

```
./configure --enable-sourcefire --enable-targetbased
```

But when i do `make` i get the following error:

```
plugbase.o: In function 'RegisterRuleOptions':
../snort-2.9.3.1/src/plugbase.c:199: undefined reference to 'SetupProfi'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is the important part of my `plugbase.c`:

```
/* built-in detection plugins */
#include "detection-plugins/sp_profinet_func.h"
...
...
...
void RegisterRuleOptions(void)
{
    LogMessage("Initializing Plug-ins!\n");

SetupProfi();
}
```

The files `sp_profinet_func.c` and `sp_profinet_func.h` are in `src/detection-plugins`.
This is the code of `sp_profinet_func.h`:

```
#ifndef __SP_PROFINET_H__
#define __SP_PROFINET_H__

void SetupProfi(void);
#ifdef DETECTION_OPTION_TREE
u_int32_t SpProfinetFunctionCodeCheckHash(void *d);
int SpProfinetFunctionCodeCheckCompare(void *l, void *r);
#endif

#endif  /* __SP_PROFINET_H__ */
```

And here is the extract of the `sp_profinet_func.c`:

```
void SetupProfi(void)
{
    printf("RULES-SetupProfi");   
     /* map the keyword to an initialization/processing function */
    RegisterRuleOption("Profinet_func", SpProfinetFunctionCodeInit, NULL, OPT_TYPE_DETECTION, NULL);
}
```

I am relatively new to C/C++ programming and compiling.
I already found out that this error can mean a linking problem but i don't know how to fix it.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem and get the detection plugin fired up?

Operating system is Debian 7.8 and I use the Snort-Version 2.9.3.1 because of recommendation of the plugins developer.

Thanks in advance!

\Chris

Comment: May be library where 'SetupProfi' is defined is missing?

Comment: Can you check the makefile for defined library?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355454/snort-make-file-gives-error

Comment: you probably have to add sp_profinet_func.c to the list of files to be compiled

Comment: When i look at the `Makefile` in /src/detection-plugins after `./configure` there is no declaration of `sp_profinet_func.c sp_profinet_func.h` and `sp_profinet_func.$(OBJEXT)` as i declared in the `Makefile.am`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
Thanks @ RP and @ Pandrei for the hint to look at the Makefile.

After `./configure` i looked at the `Makefile` (src/detection-plugins) and saw that there was no declaration of `sp_profinet_func.c sp_profinet_func.h` under "am_libspd_a_SOURCES_DIST" and also no `sp_profinet_func.$(OBJEXT)` under "am_libspd_a_OBJECTS".

I simply added these declarations and did `make` and `sudo make install` and now the preprocessor and detection-plugin are running.

Thanks for your efforts.

\Chris